# Install gcc on OS X with Xcode 4

Tags: macos, gcc, xcode4

Having reinstalled OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) I was dismayed to find that Xcode 4 no longer bundles GCC etc. How do I install the missing tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the app store doesn't install Xcode, it installs an installer. Ran the installer and the tools were installed as expected. I've left this question in case anyone makes the same mistake.